# Is it possible to update database at regular intervals of time

Tags: android, sql-update

Is It possible to update my database everyday at particular time. If so can any body help me.

providing examples are so appreciated..

Thank you so much in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `AlarmManager` APIs.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

In particular, `setRepeating()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Alarm Class for such task. just make an Alarm that get executed daily on certain time. During the execution sync your database datas.